# Can a device advertise its fqdn over UPnP?

Tags: upnp, domain-name, fqdn, ssdp

Say I want my device to be accessed by it's domain name, namely fqdn.

For background, I want to install a certificate, and client OS will validate said certificate to the domain name of the device. I cannot realistically get the certificate for an IP address. Required DNS hacks are out of scope of this question.

Where in the UPnP/SSDP `NOTIFY` message or `M-SEARCH` response can the device include own domain name?

Comment: I may be missing something but the question doesn't make sense to me. How do you think SSDP could help (even if it did hostname resolution) with validating a certificate?

Answer (score 0):

**Work in Progress**

Current plan is to advertise `LOCATION: https://mydev.somedomain.com/upnp.xml` and rely on client's stack to download that xml.

The XML will contain further relative URLs to UPnP endpoints.

Device will contain valid certificate for this fqdn, and DNS is separately hacked to resolve this fqdn to reachable ip address.

It remains to be seen if common clients (e.g. Windows network neighbourhood) agree to this.